# #appcelerator textfield color and background color not sticking

Tags: android, colors, appcelerator

I use the code below for a textfield in my project:

```js
 var textfield = Ti.UI.createTextField({
  color: 'black',
  height: '40dp',
  top: '5dp',
  left: '5dp',
  right: '50dp',
  style: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
  hintText: 'Enter an address',
  backgroundColor: '#aaa',
  paddingLeft: '5dp'
 });
```

This works on my iOS simulator and iOS devices, but not on android. I can change the color (font color) and backgroundColor on iOS and my UI will change to my desired hex color. On android, the text and background are always white, no matter what I do. On iOS I can see my hint text but on android, that is also white.

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try with custom theme for android. 
Create two file color.xml and custom_theme.xml in platform->android->res->values folder

color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="text_tab_selected">#E15151</color>
    <color name="text_tab_unselected">#8F8F8F</color>
    <color name="edit_text_hint">#ECECEC</color>
    <color name="blackcolor">#000000</color>
    <color name="whitecolor">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

custom_theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/appEditText</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.NoActionBar.Translucent" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/appEditText</item>
</style>
<style name="appEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_background</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/edit_text_hint</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

And now apply this theme to activity in Androidmanifest.xml

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".YOURACTIVITY" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Thanks

Comment: I've been sidelined by an illness but I'll give that a try. I was hoping that there was an easier answer. My four other apps on iOS and android using Appcelerator do not have this style problem, so I thought is was some obvious configuration error from moving dev computers.

Comment: Yes you are right. i was also not faced this issue in my old apps. i don't remember exact version of SDK updates but i faced this issue after updating SDK. After updating SDK i faced two issue one is for title bar and one is textfield hint text color and i got resolved it by using above code.

Comment: The fixes here should have worked but didn't. I did get my original code to work, but only after deleting my tiapp.xml and manually retyping it exactly as I had originally. Same content. I suspect if I had deleted all and retyped you code it would have worked, too. This is kind of a waste to have to delete and retype code again. This is not the first time that I've had to simply retype my code in again to make it work. Does anyone know if appcelerator studio inserts hidden control characters randomly? Twice I had to retype everything because studio minified my source code.

Comment: Instead of retyping code just try with adding androidmanifest file (Which is you will get from build folder) into platform/android folder and then apply this theme into androidManifest.xml  file.